# What kind of service for android activity?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-service, android

I am new in android programming and now i have a problem to solve.

http://s3.imgimg.de/uploads/dbmodelcdcbb1fdpng.png

If you would code this Design like in the photo from beginning:

1. What kind of service would you use for this problem?

My MainProblem is to make a Service ( I dont´t have practice with) in "ItemListActivity" which saves all Incoming Data in DB.

The second big problem is, how "ItemDetailActivity" could access the Service to get data from DB?

THX and I´m very new to android so pls don´t just answer 1 sentence, it would be great if you can show me a little framework :)

Answer (score 0):

The ItemDetailActivity should not access the service, it should work independently. All you should have to do is query the local database in the ItemDetailActivity and use the data from there.

all that other service should do is get the data and put it into the database. I recomment an `IntentService` for that

Comment: The Problem is, that on Runtime, the user switch between ItemListActivity and ItemDetailActivity, so both activities stops sometimes. How do i create a DB that is accessible independently from application lifetime?

Comment: you are thinking about this all wrong. all you do is put stuff in a database and forget it. all you have to do is query your database whenever you need data. take a look at content providers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html